# JSON File Merging With Primary Keys in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, merge, primary-key

My code was working as of yesterday but today I ran the script and started getting this error saying I can't use strings to access my JSON dictionary anymore. As I understand it, I am already iterating through my dictionary entries and it is valid JSON so I should be able to access information in it like a dictionary with string values instead of just the column number:

```
S:\Scripts\ZACH\DB MERGE>python jsonMerge.py
Beginning Merge...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jsonMerge.py", line 42, in <module>
    if intResult['SCH_NAME'] == extResult['SCH_NAME'] and intResult['SCH_CITY']
== extResult['SCH_CITY'] :
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I'm merging 2 validated JSON files like this:

```
[{"SCH_ID": "13554", "SCH_NAME": "100 Mile House Elementary", "SCH_ADDR": "Box 460, 145 North Birch", "SCH_CITY": "100 Mile House", "SCH_PROV": "BC", "SCH_PCODE": "V0K 2E0", "SCH_PHONE": "(250)395-2258", "SCH_FAX": "(250)395-3621", "SCH_DIST": "1027", "SCH_TYPE": "E", "SCH_P_REP": "FB", "SCH_G_REP": "", "SCH_P_COM": "LOC", "SCH_G_COM": "", "SCH_REBT": "10", "SCH_REBT2": "0", "SCH_P_CID": "23", "SCH_G_CID": "0", "SCH_P_CCD": "SR", "SCH_G_CCD": "", "DATE1": "", "DATE2": "", "PLAN1": "20G", "PLAN2": "2GR", "LNOPST": "FALSE"},{"SCH_ID": "16101", "SCH_NAME": "1 Step Ahead Preschool", "SCH_ADDR": "1340 Kingfisher Ave.", "SCH_CITY": "Kitimat", "SCH_PROV": "BC", "SCH_PCODE": "V8C 1G6", "SCH_PHONE": "(250)632-2288", "SCH_FAX": "", "SCH_DIST": "", "SCH_TYPE": "E", "SCH_P_REP": "FB", "SCH_G_REP": "", "SCH_P_COM": "P", "SCH_G_COM": "", "SCH_REBT": "0", "SCH_REBT2": "0", "SCH_P_CID": "23", "SCH_G_CID": "0", "SCH_P_CCD": "SR", "SCH_G_CCD": "", "DATE1": "", "DATE2": "", "PLAN1": "200", "PLAN2": "0", "LNOPST": "FALSE"},{"SCH_ID": "16736", "SCH_NAME": "1st Step Montessori", "SCH_ADDR": "8884 Russell Drive", "SCH_CITY": "Delta", "SCH_PROV": "BC", "SCH_PCODE": "V4C 4P8", "SCH_PHONE": "(604)417-3290", "SCH_FAX": "", "SCH_DIST": "1037", "SCH_TYPE": "E", "SCH_P_REP": "GF", "SCH_G_REP": "", "SCH_P_COM": "MWS", "SCH_G_COM": "", "SCH_REBT": "10", "SCH_REBT2": "0", "SCH_P_CID": "18", "SCH_G_CID": "0", "SCH_P_CCD": "SB", "SCH_G_CCD": "", "DATE1": "", "DATE2": "", "PLAN1": "20G", "PLAN2": "0", "LNOPST": "FALSE"},{"SCH_ID": "1959", "SCH_NAME": "150 Mile Elementary", "SCH_ADDR": "Box 259, 3081 Hwy. 97", "SCH_CITY": "150 Mile House", "SCH_PROV": "BC", "SCH_PCODE": "V0K 2G0", "SCH_PHONE": "(250)296-3356", "SCH_FAX": "(250)296-3291", "SCH_DIST": "1027", "SCH_TYPE": "E", "SCH_P_REP": "FB", "SCH_G_REP": "", "SCH_P_COM": "MWS", "SCH_G_COM": "", "SCH_REBT": "10", "SCH_REBT2": "0", "SCH_P_CID": "23", "SCH_G_CID": "0", "SCH_P_CCD": "SR", "SCH_G_CCD": "", "DATE1": "9/12/2018", "DATE2": "10/30/2018", "PLAN1": "2GS", "PLAN2": "2GR", "LNOPST": "FALSE"}]
```

and:

```
[{"District Number": "82", "School Code": "8297024", "SCH_NAME": "Na Aksa Gyilak'yoo", "SCH_ADDR": "PO Box 544 STN Main", "SCH_CITY": "Terrace", "SCH_PROV": "BC", "SCH_PCODE": "V8G 4B5", "Principal Title": "Mrs", "Principal First name": "Colleen", "Principal Last Name": "Austin", "School Type": "Standard School", "Grade Range": "K-12", "School Category": "Independent School", "Funding Group(s)": "2", "NLC: Early Learning": "no", "NLC: Afterschool": "no", "NLC: Cont. Ed.": "no", "NLC: Seniors": "no", "NLC: Comm. Sport": "no", "NLC: Comm. Use": "no", "NLC: Integr. Svcs.": "no", "SCH_PHONE": "(250)615-2844", "SCH_FAX": "(250)615-2833", "Email": "kalumteacher@gmail.com", "Enrolment Total": "80", "Enrolment As Of": "September 30 2018", "KH Enrolment": "1", "KF Enrolment": "11", "HS Registration": "0", "SU Enrolment": "0", "EU Enrolment": "0", "Grade 1 Enrolment": "2", "Grade 2 Enrolment": "8", "Grade 3 Enrolment": "4", "Grade 4 Enrolment": "5", "Grade 5 Enrolment": "4", "Grade 6 Enrolment": "8", "Grade 7 Enrolment": "4", "Grade 8 Enrolment": "9", "Grade 9 Enrolment": "5", "Grade 10 Enrolment": "11", "Grade 11 Enrolment": "3", "Grade 12 Enrolment": "5"}]
```

using SCH_NAME and SCH_CITY as the primary keys:

```
with open(extFile, 'r') as extF:
        #Iterate through every entry
        for extLine in extF:
            hasMatched = False
            #load line
            extResult = json.loads(extLine)
            #print ("Checking: " + intResult['SCH_NAME'] + '\n')
            #Set context as the external result to start us off
            #contextLine = extResult
            with open(intFile, 'r') as intF:
                #Iterate through every entry
                for intLine in intF:
                    #Load line
                    intResult = json.loads(intLine)
                    #print ("Matching: " + extResult['SCH_NAME'] + '\n')
                    #Check if rows match
                    if intResult['SCH_NAME'] == extResult['SCH_NAME'] and intResult['SCH_CITY'] == extResult['SCH_CITY'] :
                        #We have a match
                        hasMatched = True
```

Can anyone help shine a light on what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Just looking at the error, it thinks `intResult` and/or `extResult` is a list, you probably want them to be dictionaries

Comment: Why keeping the dicts in lists? Just "remove the []" or add a [0] before the key indexing.

Comment: Without the "[]" encapsulating all of the entries json.loads in unable to use the data though. Adding "[0]" before the key only allows me access to the first entry, not all 5000 I am dealing with. I even tried to then nest another for loop to iterate through [0] to [5000] but then it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yea ok looking at the error and the two json files, they're coming in as lists instead of dicts. You may want to figure out why this happened, but you can do a quick workaround like so.

```
intResult = json.loads(intLine)[0]
```

note you may need to do the same for `extResult`

Comment: This allows the code to run but only calls the first entry. Trying to loop through them like this just gives me more errors too.

Comment: File "jsonMerge.py", line 34, in <module>
    extResult = json.loads(eL)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init
__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decode
r.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

Comment: File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decode
r.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)